# How to delete node selected in ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to delete child node that is selected in comboBox.

```
private void AccountsSetup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populating parent nodes with the items in Bank ComboBox that is First.
    string[] items = new string[BankList.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < BankList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        items[i] = BankList.Items[i].ToString();
        //node.Nodes.Add(items[i]);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(items[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Despite of writing find node which is in Accounts comboBox, it does not find and obviously does not delete.

```
// If the Account No matches to Account node, it should delete.
TreeNode[] nodes = treeView1.Nodes.Find(AccountsComboBox2.Text, true);

foreach (TreeNode oldnode in nodes)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Remove(oldnode);
}
```

**My add account code, maybe i am doing something wrong here:**

```
 treeView1.Nodes[BankList.SelectedIndex].Nodes.Add(AccountNotextBox1.Text);
        treeView1.ExpandAll();
```

the added account goes to AccountComboBox2.

so then I select AccountComboBox2.Text and matches if the node exist in treeview then delete it.

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to find the selected item. Also, you can't remove an item from a collection while you're iterating it.

Comment: when I press "Delete Account" Button, it iterates through treeView1.nodes and find if the Account No" 123123123 exist, and if it exist, it should delete the node.

Comment: i cannot delete item while iterating it? then do I have to select node for deletion? what if I do not want user to select node to delete, because when the account is created it goes into comboBox and when a user selects comboBox account to delete, everything works. I'm just adding treeview so that user can know where bank they have account in.

Comment: Should work just fine, are you sure you named the control correctly ? Or there might be something wrong with your check of *If the Account No matches to Account node*

Comment: @Jim thats where I'm stucked.

Comment: @Patrick the only thing you have to do is to give the node a `Name` and `Text`, like so. `treeView1.Nodes[BankList.SelectedIndex].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode {Name = AccountNotextBox1.Text, Text = AccountNotextBox1.Text});`

Comment: yeah thanks its solved

Comment: try to use Add(AccountNotextBox1.Text, AccountNotextBox1.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  add `Cast<TreeNode>` and use `Where` like this.But first add Tag when you create new node.

First edit your function which add new node

```
   TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(AccountNotextBox1.Text);
            //this is tag
            newNode.Tag = AccountsComboBox2.Text;
            treeView1.Nodes[BankList.SelectedIndex].Nodes.Add(newNode);
```

And next find node by `Tag`

```
TreeNode[] treeNodes = treeView1.Nodes
                                .Cast<TreeNode>()
                                .Where(r => r.Tag == AccountsComboBox2.Text)
                                .ToArray();

foreach (TreeNode oldnode in treeNodes)
 {
    if (oldnode.Parent == null)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Remove(oldnode);
    }
    else
    {
        oldnode.Parent.Nodes.Remove(oldnode);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Patrick Try check  you try remove node which have parent or not as i show.

Comment: it's still there, it is not deleting, do I need to refresh or something?

Comment: Node is null, I modified your code to check that, and it's spitting null. What does it mean, if I'm adding new nodes to parent and its even showing, despite that the node is null?

Comment: I added this code into your code node = treeView1.SelectedNode after selecting the account node, when I hit remove, it did removed. but I do not want user to select node, I want user to select it in comboBox to remove in treeview. This means if I do not select a node, node is null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128069/discussion-between-mww-and-patrick).

Comment: this guy mww deserves an award!